# SingleLiveEvent with conditional trigger

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-nested-fragment, mutablelivedata

I am using nested fragments so fragment1 opens fragment2 and they share a viewmodel.
This viewmodel calls a repository to get data and using a LiveData it posts the result and then fragment2 displays the data.

My problem was the second time fragment1 opened fragment2, for a brief moment fragment2 was displaying the previous data. I could solve this problem using a similar approach to this post [Android Arch Components ViewModel and LiveData trigger after screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450215/android-arch-components-viewmodel-and-livedata-trigger-after-screen-rotation) using SingleLiveEvent.

However, now my issue is that on screen rotation, data is not delivered again (since it is done a single time) and fragment2 screen remains blank.

I was thinking on modifying SingleLiveEvent so it sometimes delivers data a single time but other times to make it deliver again using a condition or something similar.

Does anybody knows what approach could I use here?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom `LifeCycleObserver` class and attaching it to the `Fragment`. You can find how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58511176/9722336)

Comment: Also you can stick to the `LiveData` class and don't need to use special `LiveData` subclasses. This would be beautifully solved by checking the concept of Lifecycles especially in the case of Fragments. I'd recommend that you read about it